# The multi-part identifier could not be found in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I am doing condition and in that I am inserting data in a table at that time it showing error i.e. "The multi-part identifier could not be found" in sqlserver

Here is my query

```
SELECT CASE 

            WHEN p.id = tmp.ProductId and p.Deleted = 0 and p.Published = 1 and  p.VisibleIndividually = 1 
               THEN

        Insert into mysql_abc_Product(ProductId, abcStatus, IsDeleted, InTime, StoreId,LanguageId) 
        select DISTINCT tmp.ProductId,1,0,GETDATE(),s.Id,l.Id from  Language l,  Store s, #temp tmp, Product p left join Incremental_Solr_Product isp on isp.ProductId = p.Id  
        where isp.Id is NULL and p.Deleted = 'False' or p.Published = 'True' or  VisibleIndividually = 'True'

               ELSE 

        Insert into mysql_abc_Product(ProductId, abcStatus, IsDeleted, InTime, StoreId,LanguageId) 
        select DISTINCT tmp.ProductId,1,0,GETDATE(),s.Id,l.Id from  Language l,  Store s, #temp tmp, Product p left join Incremental_Solr_Product isp on isp.ProductId = p.Id  
        where isp.Id is NULL and p.Deleted = 'True' or p.Published = 'False' or  VisibleIndividually = 'False'

       END as Saleable, * 
FROM Language l, Store s, Product p left outer join #temp tmp on tmp.productid = p.Id where isp.Id is NULL
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  In this case, it should fix your problem.

Comment: Yah that's right. But by using join syntax also coming same issues.

Comment: You are looking for isp.Id in your Where clause on the last line, yet there is no table qualified with isp in the From statement.

Comment: After your case statement you are selecting * from all the tables.... there is probably a column which has the same name in more than one of your table.s Remove the * with explicit column names.

Comment: AFAICT, you cannot mix a SELECT statement with INSERT statements. You should be using [IF ... ELSE ...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms182717.aspx) construct to do the inserts.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the proper joins into this, but here is your solution to the above query. You did not include the table "Incremental_Solr_Product" qualified with "isp" into your last line From statement.

```
SELECT CASE 

            WHEN p.id = tmp.ProductId and p.Deleted = 0 and p.Published = 1 and  p.VisibleIndividually = 1 
               THEN

        Insert into Incremental_Solr_Product(ProductId, SolrStatus, IsDeleted, InTime, StoreId,LanguageId) 
        select DISTINCT tmp.ProductId,1,0,GETDATE(),s.Id,l.Id from  Language l,  Store s, #temp tmp, Product p left join Incremental_Solr_Product isp on isp.ProductId = p.Id  
        where isp.Id is NULL and p.Deleted = 'False' or p.Published = 'True' or  VisibleIndividually = 'True'

               ELSE 

        Insert into Incremental_Solr_Product(ProductId, SolrStatus, IsDeleted, InTime, StoreId,LanguageId) 
        select DISTINCT tmp.ProductId,1,0,GETDATE(),s.Id,l.Id from  Language l,  Store s, #temp tmp, Product p left join Incremental_Solr_Product isp on isp.ProductId = p.Id  
        where isp.Id is NULL and p.Deleted = 'True' or p.Published = 'False' or  VisibleIndividually = 'False'

       END as Saleable, * 
FROM Language l, Store s, Product p left outer join #temp tmp on tmp.productid = p.Id 
left join Incremental_Solr_Product isp on isp.ProductId = p.Id
where isp.Id is NULL
```